# Missing hibernate ORM snapshot in pom.xml

Tags: hibernate, maven, configuration

I'm trying to test Hibernate ORM snapshot 7.0.0 but I'm getting an error while trying to add it as a dependency in `pom.xml`:

> *Missing artifact org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT*

What am I doing wrong?

URL for repository is given on Hibernate website: [here](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/6.5/#snapshots)

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <hibernate-core.version>7.0.0-SNAPSHOT</hibernate-core.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>hibernate-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/hibernate/orm/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also tried this one from other StackOverflow answer but the result is the same:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>allow-snapshots</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots-repo</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: The 7 version you are trying is older (by 6 months) then the 6.5 that is mentioned on the website. So I suspect even if you could it wouldn't even work and has been relabeled to 6.something. Use the 6.5 if you want to try something.

Comment: @M.Deinum I already tested 6.5 and now I'd like to test 7 to be prepared once it becomes a release. That should be possible for sure, but I'm not such and expert for maven repos and I'm asking for help with it.

Comment: As I mentioned the 7.x version is old more then 6 months old, so I suspect it was some of the 6.2 or something release that got relabeled. I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @M.Deinum The work on 7 branch in parallel no matter the date resleased. That should be possible to add as a dependency and should be possible to test. The same story was with 6 minor version - it was developed in parallel with latest 5 releases. Please accept my apologies but I'm sure you're wrong with this one.

Comment: Well the only difference should be the version so if it works with 6.5 it should work for 7. If it doesn't the metadata is borked.

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, that's not correct because 6.5 is available as a RC, and 7.0 is available only as a snapshot To get a snapshot you have to configure additional repository and that was my original question. It is completely legal and sane idea to test next major version in development environment to check what is going tochange and how much effort you have to put in adopting new major version. And snapshot is the option to check it in early stage. So it's not about versions but rather about configuring repository - this is what I failed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing what was wrong is a direcory:

WRONG directory: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/hibernate/orm/

CORRECT directory: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>hibernate-snapshots</id>
       <name>Hibernate snapshots</name>
       <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```